# I don't quite understand why my navigation path isn't firing

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to understand why the navigation path doesn't work when I click the login screen button.

It looks like the path is being sent but then isn't quite working as expected. When I count the path, it does show 2 which makes sense, so why doesn't it display the login view?

I am trying to replicate the coordinator pattern, show each screen should have it's own router, screen and viewModel.

Link to project

https://github.com/mickeysox/TestCoordinator

Main App router that initiates the navigation path

```
class AppFlowState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var path = NavigationPath()
}

class AppRouter: AppFlowState{

    @ObservedObject var state = AppFlowState()

    @ViewBuilder func route(to destination: AppRoutes) -> some View {
        switch destination {
        case .home:
            self.homeScreen()
        }
    }
    func homeRoute() {
        self.path.append(AppRoutes.home)
        print(path.count)
    }
    
    private func homeScreen() -> some View {
        let router = HomeRouter(path: path)
        let screen = HomeScreen(router: router)
        return screen
    }
}
```

App screen that should route the views

```
struct AppScreen: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var router = AppRouter()
    
    @ViewBuilder private func content() -> some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                self.router.homeRoute()
            } label: {
                Text("Home Screen")
            }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)

        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: self.$router.path) {
            content()
                .navigationDestination(for: AppRoutes.self) { screen in
                    router.route(to: screen)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class HomeRouter: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var path: NavigationPath
    
    init(path: NavigationPath) {
        self.path = path
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder func router(to destination: HomeRoutes) -> some View {
        switch destination {
        case .login:
            self.loginScreen()
        }
    }
    
    func loginRoute() {
        path.append(HomeRoutes.login)
    }
    
    private func loginScreen() -> some View {
        LoginScreen()
    }
    
}
```

```
struct HomeScreen: View {
    @State var router: HomeRouter
    
    
    @ViewBuilder private func content() -> some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                self.router.loginRoute()
            } label: {
                Text("Login Screen")
            }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)

        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
            content()
                .navigationDestination(for: HomeRoutes.self) { screen in
                    router.router(to: screen)
                }
    }

}
```

Comment: `@ObservedObject` only works in a SwiftUI `View` or `DynamicProperty` `AppRouter` is neither. Also, `@State` only fires when the "value" changes, `class` is a reference type, its value/reference/address doesn't change when when a variable changes.

Comment: `Observations`: nesting ObservableObjects can produce problems. In your case, you inherit from one, `class AppRouter: AppFlowState` **and** then you declared another one inside it,  
    `@ObservedObject var state = AppFlowState()`. As mentioned don't use `@ObservedObject` inside a class, only in a View. 
    In `HomeScreen` you declare `@State var router: HomeRouter`, it should be something like, `@ObservedObject var router: HomeRouter`. You create `Views` inside a class, eg `HomeScreen` in `class HomeRouter`, views should be inside other views.
         Restructure your code.

Comment: routers and view models are unnecessary